# timestampTz fields in Laravel

Tags: laravel, php-carbon, timestamp-with-timezone

Laravel 5.4 supports the Postgres `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` field type in migrations:

```
$table->timestampTz('scheduled_for');
```

Laravel can be set up to convert date fields (`DATE`, `DATETIME`, `TIMESTAMP`) into Carbon objects (and does so by default for the `created_at` and `updated_at` `TIMESTAMP` fields), but putting `scheduled_for` into the `$dates` field causes an error with the timezone-aware version:

```
InvalidArgumentException with message 'Trailing data'
```

Looking in the database and tinker, the field's value appears to be something like `2017-06-19 19:19:19-04`. Is there a native way to get a Carbon object out of one of these field types? Or am I stuck using an accessor?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Resurrecting this question, hopefully with a helpful answer that gets accepted.

Laravel assumes a `Y-m-d H:i:s` database timestamp format. If you're using a Postgres `timestampz` column, that's obviously different. You need to tell Eloquent how to get Carbon to parse that format.

Simply define the `$dateFormat` property on your model like so:

```
Class MyModel extends Eloquent {

    protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:sO';

}
```

Credit where credit is due: I found this solution in a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/bosnadev/database/issues/15#issuecomment-293782303)

Comment: Neato, that's elegant!

Comment: What if I have both `timestamp` and `timestampTz` column types on the same table/Model/?

Comment: @Inigo It's been a while since I've head to deal with this -- but I _assume_ you'll have to write something a little more extensive that involves making a hash that holds the `column -> format` mapping and then override the method that is looking up the `$dateFormat` and perform the lookup on your own, then return the correct/desired.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @Jim. I ended up simply storing the timezone in a different field but I'll bear this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Put this inside your model

```
protected $casts = [
    'scheduled_for' => 'datetime'   // date | datetime | timestamp
];
```

Using `$dates` is more likely obsolete as `$casts` do the same stuff (maybe except `$dateFormat` attribute which can work only for `$dates` fields iirc, but I saw some complaining on it)

**Edit**

I was testing Carbon once on Laravel 5.4 and I created a trait for it

**this is not production level code yet** so include it in your model on your own risk

```
<?php namespace App\Traits;

use Carbon\Carbon;

trait castTrait
{
    protected function castAttribute($key, $value)
    {
        $database_format        = 'Y-m-d H:i:se';   // Store this somewhere in config files
        $output_format_date     = 'd/m/Y';          // Store this somewhere in config files
        $output_format_datetime = 'd/m/Y H:i:s';    // Store this somewhere in config files

        if (is_null($value)) {
            return $value;
        }

        switch ($this->getCastType($key)) {
            case 'int':
            case 'integer':
                return (int) $value;
            case 'real':
            case 'float':
            case 'double':
                return (float) $value;
            case 'string':
                return (string) $value;
            case 'bool':
            case 'boolean':
                return (bool) $value;
            case 'object':
                return $this->fromJson($value, true);
            case 'array':
            case 'json':
                return $this->fromJson($value);
            case 'collection':
                return new BaseCollection($this->fromJson($value));
            case 'date':
                Carbon::setToStringFormat($output_format_date);
                $date = (string)$this->asDate($value);
                Carbon::resetToStringFormat();  // Just for sure
                return $date;
            case 'datetime':
                Carbon::setToStringFormat($output_format_datetime);
                $datetime = (string)$this->asDateTime($value);
                Carbon::resetToStringFormat();
                return $datetime;
            case 'timestamp':
                return $this->asTimestamp($value);
            default:
                return $value;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Return a timestamp as DateTime object with time set to 00:00:00.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return \Carbon\Carbon
     */
    protected function asDate($value)
    {
        return $this->asDateTime($value)->startOfDay();
    }

    /**
     * Return a timestamp as DateTime object.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return \Carbon\Carbon
     */
    protected function asDateTime($value)
    {
        $carbon = null;
        $database_format = [ // This variable should also be in config file
            'datetime'  => 'Y-m-d H:i:se',      // e -timezone
            'date'      => 'Y-m-d'
        ];

        if(empty($value)) {
            return null;
        }

        // If this value is already a Carbon instance, we shall just return it as is.
        // This prevents us having to re-instantiate a Carbon instance when we know
        // it already is one, which wouldn't be fulfilled by the DateTime check.
        if ($value instanceof Carbon) {
            $carbon = $value;
        }

         // If the value is already a DateTime instance, we will just skip the rest of
         // these checks since they will be a waste of time, and hinder performance
         // when checking the field. We will just return the DateTime right away.
        if ($value instanceof DateTimeInterface) {
            $carbon = new Carbon(
                $value->format($database_format['datetime'], $value->getTimezone())
            );
        }

        // If this value is an integer, we will assume it is a UNIX timestamp's value
        // and format a Carbon object from this timestamp. This allows flexibility
        // when defining your date fields as they might be UNIX timestamps here.
        if (is_numeric($value)) {
            $carbon = Carbon::createFromTimestamp($value);
        }

        // If the value is in simply year, month, day format, we will instantiate the
        // Carbon instances from that format. Again, this provides for simple date
        // fields on the database, while still supporting Carbonized conversion.
        if ($this->isStandardDateFormat($value)) {
            $carbon = Carbon::createFromFormat($database_format['date'], $value)->startOfDay();
        }

        // Finally, we will just assume this date is in the format used by default on
        // the database connection and use that format to create the Carbon object
        // that is returned back out to the developers after we convert it here.
        $carbon = Carbon::createFromFormat(
            $database_format['datetime'], $value
        );

        return $carbon;
    }
}
```

Comment: `$casts` doesn't appear to work. It still appears to be running it through Carbon (unsuccessfully).

Comment: The reason is wrong format that comes from database. Laravel is trying to parse your input datetime string using incorrect format mask

Comment: Given that Laravel supports `timestampTz` in migrations, it can't really be called the "wrong" format. Thus far it appears Laravel doesn't *fully* support it, hence my question - it seems odd to implement it in migrations without it being particularly usable in the actual code.

Comment: I updated my answer, you can test the trait I provided

Comment: I'm leaning towards just using a `timestamp` field and storing `scheduled_tz` alongside it as a string, allowing me to do an accessor like `public function getScheduledForAttribute($value) {
        return Carbon::parse($value)->setTimezone($this->scheduled_tz);
    }`

Comment: My solution do this, but you will not need to declare attribute functions, so it's even better