# How to insert into Postgres dateTimeTz with Laravel and Carbon?

Tags: laravel, postgresql-9.1, php-carbon

I want to use the Postgres timstamp with timezone data type.

My migration has this line:

```
$table->dateTimeTz('local_timestamp');
```

I try to seed like this:

```
$note->local_timestamp = Carbon::now();
```

I have also tried to format it like this when I seed it:

```
$note->local_timestamp = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:sO');
```

I retrieve my seeded data like this:

```
$data = Note::where('owner', $owner)->get();
```

And I get an InvalidArgumentException "Data missing" in Carbon error that shows this:

```
at Carbon::rawCreateFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:sO', '2019-03-28 14:02:42', null)
```

I have tried including this line in my model because I've seen it suggested as the answer on other similar questions:

```
protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:sO';
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the date format from the model fixed the problem.

This answer is very useful - [Laravel Carbon Data Missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968061/laravel-carbon-data-missing)

I changed the date format based on this answer - [timestampTz fields in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44639221/timestamptz-fields-in-laravel) - which deals with the timestamptz data type (not datetimetz)