# Understand Laravel's timezone

Tags: laravel, postgresql, laravel-6

I'm trying to understand the following.

On my `config/app.php` I'm having my local timezone set to:

```
'timezone' => 'Europe/Athens'
```

My `Postgres` is set to:

```
SHOW timezone; // returns UTC
```

In the inserted rows in `Postgres` i would expect to see my local timezone, converted to UTC. **Instead, the timestamp is written on my local timezone**.

In another `Node.js` application, in which I'm working on, with another `Postgres` instance, when i insert a new row, the local timezone is converted to UTC while the timestamp is stored.

Why this is different on my `Laravel` app?

What is the case here?

Comment: Laravel uses the timezone you define in the config. A good practice is to keep `UTC` in Laravel and convert to user timezone when needed when presenting the date or convert to UTC when user enter the date. Using timezone in the application may cause issues when working with date. A known example: https://github.com/techouse/php-date-interval-timezone-bug

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier This is quite useful and thanks. Though i still do not understand why Postgres keeps the same timestamp as in laravel and why does not convert it to UTC.

Comment: Does this helps ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44639221/timestamptz-fields-in-laravel